# JDBC Autocommit to false in application level

Tags: java, oracle, performance, jdbc

When most of the best programming approaches recommend to set the JDBC auto commit to false, what is the rational behind JDBC API design that set the default value to true?

Comment: Can you show us few references to justify your statement ?

Comment: Probably because it is easier to use and for simple applications it is enough

Comment: @javaguy Here you go https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/Non-transactionalDataAccessAndTheAuto-commitMode

Comment: please note that you could configure your datasource in your AS in such way that it will be its responsibility to manage the transactions, you will then have no more than one tx per request which can give even better performances than managing the tx yourself

Answer (score 1):

**What is the rational behind JDBC API design that set the default value to true?**

You will take transactions under your control by setting `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` only when you are dealing **multiple `INSERT/UPDATE` sql queries (handling through JDBC) within/across database tables as an atomic operation**, which is only needed for a medium/complex sized applications.

Now, if all transactions have to be handled explicitly (i.e., as you suggested if `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` is by default), then the developers should be very careful even for single `INSERT/UPDATE` sql query  (handling through JDBC) by ensuring that the `commit`() and `rollback`() have been handled properly, otherwise the `connection` will be hanging and it is quite hard to debug.

> If auto-commit mode has been disabled, the method commit must be
>   called explicitly in order to commit changes; otherwise, database
>   changes will not be saved.

You can look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html)

Following your approach i.e., calling `commit` explicitly for each and every transaction is unnecessary and if we ignore do it even once, it will do more harm than good.

Comment: Note that ORM frameworks handle this for you in their transactions APIs. Connection is obtained, commit is set to false if needed, then commit is called at the end of the tx.

Comment: @AngerClown I agree with you, I did not mention it as he is talking specifically about explicit commit

Answer (score 0):

Similar to why we use logging frameworks instead of `System.out.println`.

The simplest setup is for the simplest cases.  Autocommitting is right for trivial usages and applications.  Simple cases don't need well defined transaction boundaries, so in the interest of Keeping It Simple, autocommit defaults to true.

Wikipedia has a pretty good article on DB transactions, worth a read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction